# Getting EOFError from retrlines() when using FTP_TLS from python ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib, ftps

This one is not making any sense to me. Apologies for my poor python, I'm relatively new to the language.

The pertinent part of my program looks like:

```py
from ftplib import FTP, FTP_TLS

...

        try:
            ftps = FTP(server, user = user, passwd = password,
            encoding='ISO8859-1'
            )
            # ftps.prot_p()
            login = True
        except:
            print("Login failed, retry")
...
        for member in members:

            ftps.retrlines(f'RETR {member}', lines.append)

            fp = open(f'{dest}/{type}/{member}{sep}{suffix}', 'w',
                    encoding='ISO8859-1', errors='backslashreplace')
            line_number = 0
            for line in lines:
                line_number += 1
                bad = [line_number, line]
                line = line.replace('\xdd', '|')

                try:
                    fp.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                except:
                    print(f"line {bad[0]} in {type} member:",
                          f"{member}{sep}{suffix} - {bad[1]}")
            fp.close()
...
```

This works fine and has been for a couple of years.  However, when I change it to:

```
            ftps = FTP_TLS(server, user = user, passwd = password,
            encoding='ISO8859-1'
            )
            ftps.prot_p()
            login = True
```

I get:
File "~\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ftplib.py", line 218, in getline
raise EOFError
EOFError

I tried wrapping the ftps.retrlines() in a try/except clause to ignore the EOFError (a suggestion from another SO thread) but that caused even more ssl errors.

I've looked at the files on the server and after they were downloaded (at least it is consistent where the error occurs) and don't see anything in the source file to cause this.  Looking at the (server) file immediately prior to and following the file "in error", both look fine and download without issues if I don't use FTP_TLS.

Full disclosure, the server is a z/OS server with FTPS enabled and these are members of PDSs on z/OS.

TIA

Comment: Oops, FTP is a rather old protocol and is known to cause headaches if firewalls are on the way. Are any firewall involved in your configuration? If the answer is yes you should contact the firewall admin...

Comment: No firewalls within the environment.  I use FTPS via WinSCP and FileZilla just fine and the first 204 items (of a couple of thousand) transfer fine with my program.  Additionally, all files are transferred if i use the FTP class rather than the FTP_TLS class.

Comment: There are other config traps. FTP can use either active (the server initiates the data connection) or passive (the client initializes the data connection) modes. And in FTPS, the command and data channels can be separately TLS encrypted. If for any reason the client and server do not use same options it can result in the data connection aborting.

Comment: But wouldn't that happen on the first transfer, rather than after 204 successful transfers? And the only code changes between a completely successful run and one that gets the EOFError is initializing TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I got this working with:

```
    while member := Paths.current_member().lower():
        sourcefile = f'{Paths.current_source}({member})'
        if myType in exceptions and member in exceptions[myType]:
            logit(f'Skipping {sourcefile}')
            Paths.next_member()
            continue
        logit(f'Retrieving {sourcefile}')
        lines.clear()
        try:
            myFTP.connection.retrlines(f'RETR {member}', lines.append)
        except:
            print(f'Error retrieving {sourcefile}, retrying')
            myFTP.re_connect()        #log back in
            myFTP.connection.cwd(f"'{Paths.current_source}'")
            continue                  #try again

        suffix = suffixes.get(myType, '')
        sep = '.' if suffix else ''
        destfile = f'{Paths.current_dest}/{member}{sep}{suffix}'
        logit(f'Saving to {destfile}')
        fp = open(destfile, 'w',
                encoding='ISO8859-1', errors='backslashreplace')
        line_number = 0
        for line in lines:
            line_number += 1
            bad = [line_number, line]
            line = line.replace('\xdd', '|')
            try:
                fp.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
            except:
                print(f"line {bad[0]} in {myType} member:",
                      f"{member}{sep}{suffix} - {bad[1]}")
        fp.close()
        Paths.next_member()
```

myFTP is a class I created to store FTP related information and Paths stores source and destination paths.  I could have used a bunch of global variables but thought the classes were a bit more pythonic.

Apparently the server has some limit on the amount of data that can be transferred via FTPS and cuts it off after a while.  Adding the re-connect/retry logic solved the issue.

Maybe this will help someone else trying to implement mass transfers with via FTPS.